# Create an unique ID in Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, oracle11g

Is it preferred to always create an unique ID in an Oracle database? I know that the Oracle database automatically creates a field `ROWID` which is unique, but if I reorganize the database due to performance issuses wont all my ROWIDs be changed/restructured so the IDs I have used in other application will be broken?

Comment: Question is a bit broad: In generall don't use internal (technical) ids as references. Not even inside the scope of your database and surely not outside. Create (functional) ids yourself.

Comment: It depends on your application

Answer (score 0):

When using any relational database you should create unique artificial keys if your data does not naturally contain a value or combination of values which are unique. An Oracle ROWID encodes a physical address in the database and should **never** be stored in a table. A ROWID is only guaranteed to be constant for the duration of a single transaction. Various types of operations on the database, including partition key updates, Flashback Table operations, and shrink table operations. [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1846) for further information.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: There are more cases where the ROWID can change. An UPDATE can change the rowid if the row needs to be moved to a different block